# Is this a valid jUnit Pattern

Tags: java, jdbc, junit

I want to test pushing and pulling data from a database. Will this pattern work?

Specifically, will using this pattern successfully push and pull from the database and will it clean up afterwards?

```
private Connection connection;
private Savepoint savepoint;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    connection = MyConnectionGenerator();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    savepoint = connection.setSavepoint();
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception{
    //use the connection for CRUD ops testing
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    connection.rollback(savepoint);
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: It should, did you try it?

Comment: I did. I'm worried that there is something wrong with it that I'm not checking. I get a green bar and the data isn't in the db at the end... so maybe it works.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about exactly what your test is designed to verify? Because it looks like you are doing a lot of work, just to verify  that the database handles `SavePoint` transaction demarcation correctly - basically unit testing the database. Is the unit test code you shared part of a larger effort - maybe you are looking for a repeatable way to capture, apply, and erase data state snapshots? So that you don't have to repeat all of the steps in a business process just to prime the data for every test over-and-over?

Comment: @SeanMickey the myTest method could test things like cascade deletes and proper data restrictions. But the emphasis of my question is will this always reset the database back to the state it was before or is there a way for the changes to leak out?